# Adding new element to dictionary in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I would like to add new item to on my dictionary in my code,

```
public PvmPivotResponse Report_GetGmrToTypeOfIPP(int ProjectPeriodId, int ResearchGroupId)
{
      PvmPivotResponse retVal = new PvmPivotResponse();

      var nodes = GetSalesHierarchyData();
      var flatNodes = nodes.FlattenTree(d => d.Id, d => d.ParentId);

      var results = flatNodes.Select(
       list => list
      .Select((d, i) => new KeyValuePair<int, FlatData>(i, d))
      .ToDictionary(pair => string.Format("level{0}", pair.Key + 1), 
                    pair => pair.Value.Text))
      .ToList();

       retVal.Data = 
            new List<object>{
                JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { data = results },
                                            Formatting.Indented)
            };

      return retVal;
}
```

This my Json output, but I need to add new item to my dictionary it's called 'value'

```
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "level1": "XXXXXX",
          "level2": "XXXXXX",
          "level3": "XXXXXX",
          "level4": "XXXXXX "
        },
       ]
    }
```

then my new output should be like this,

```
{
      "data": [
        {
          "level1": "XXXXXX",
          "level2": "XXXXXX",
          "level3": "XXXXXX",
          "level4": "XXXXXX ",
          "val": "2"
        },
       ]
    }
```

so how can I add this ('value') new item on my dictionary??

After the answers I have decided to give more details for a clear understanding, 
 Well, I have got hierarchic data then for fetch them I have used   RecursiveExtensions, please take a look [[here]](http://prntscr.com/6ly5mx) so While I have using this methods, I fetched some data from dbContext, like this.

```
public IEnumerable<FlatData> GetSalesHierarchyData()
{
    IEnumerable<FlatData> _salesHieararchy = db.SalesHierarchy
    .Select(s =>
    new FlatData()
    {
      Id = s.Id,
      ParentId = s.ParentId ?? 0,
      Text = s.Name,
      Val = 2 //This has been added after, normally it doesn't exist before.  
      }).ToList();
      return _salesHieararchy;
}
```

Comment: Don't convert the dictionary to a list. Then you can simply call `.Add(....)` on it.

Comment: What does the output of `FlattenTree` look like?  What does a `FlatNode` look like?

Comment: Please take a look [here](http://prntscr.com/6ly5mx)] ,

Answer (score 3):

Assuming I understand what you want, it might be as simple as this:

```
  var results1 = flatNodes.Select(
   list => list
  .Select((d, i) => new KeyValuePair<int, FlatData>(i, d))
  .ToDictionary(pair => string.Format("level{0}", pair.Key + 1), pair => pair.Value.Text));

  results1.Add("val", 2); // Add your extra value.

  var results = results1.ToList();

   retVal.Data = new List<object>{JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { data = results }, Formatting.Indented)};

  return retVal;
```

I don't understand, though, why you create an `IEnumerable` of `KeyValuePair<int, FlatData>`, turn that into a dictionary, and then turn that into a list.  There seem to be some extra steps there.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't wok for me, so that I have more details  on my post, I hope it could be more clear than before.

Comment: When you say "It doesn't work for me", do you mean that it throws an error? Or that it's not suitable for the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: basically, I have tried to add your code part on mine, results.Add("","""), unfortunately, intellisense doesn't identify it, then actually  I don't want such as thing I mean, after the  all levels completed, I would like to put "Val" to end of of dictionary and return Json format, Also I have updated my post, you can get more details above about them.

Answer (score 1):

just add the Add method

```
 var dic = flatNodes.Select(
   list => list
  .Select((d, i) => new KeyValuePair<int, FlatData>(i, d))
  .ToDictionary(pair => string.Format("level{0}", pair.Key + 1), pair => pair.Value.Text));

  dic.Add("val", "2");

  var results = dic.ToList()
```

Comment: thanks @Paulo, but it doesn't work for me, thanks again.

Comment: When you say "It doesn't work for me", do you mean that it throws an error? Or that it's not suitable for the problem you're trying to solve?